# Ubuntu Mail Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

I was looking to start a simple email service for the users of my website, meaning they'll be able to get an @mydomain.tld email. I have an Ubuntu server and I was wondering two things:

1. How do I install a mail server
2. Are there any scripts I could base the web client off of (like registering your email, logging in, sending mail, etc)

I've already found a few tutorials, but they aren't too helpful. All I really need is #2, as I could probably figure #1 out if I spent more time on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any scripts I could base the web client off of (like registering your email, logging in, sending mail, etc)

There are webmails like [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) and whole suits like [Zimbra](https://www.zimbra.com/).